# HTML: Having problems creating submenus, how do you create a third level of menus?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, navigationbar

I'm beginning to make a website and I managed to make a navigation bar, with the first set of menus. The second set took awhile, but I managed to make. But now I would like to make a third set of submenu, but I have no idea how. Sort of like this image: http://vista-buttons.com/vista-skin/images/help/1_3.gif. Where a visitor has the choice to hover their mouse over products > submenu item 1 > submenu item 1_2
Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="nav_wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Menu1</a></li><li>
<a href="">Menu1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Menu2</a>
</li></ul><li>
<a href="">Menu1</a></li><li>
<a href="">Menu1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%">
<img src="unknown.jpg" style='width:100%;height:100%'/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#nav{
    background-color: #222;
}
#nav-wrapper{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    tex-align: left;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a,visited{
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul ul li{
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a,visited{
    color: #ccc
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color: #099;
}
div#nav{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Sorry if the question is too simple, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Fiddle Example..

```
<ul class="top-level-menu">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Offices</a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">New York</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q8CYC/7/)